# Is it possible to create a Parse object from JSON

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am more or less convinced that it is possible to write my own code, inspecting the JSON and creating an object based on that.

But I am hoping that I have missed some part of the documentation, cause it would be nice to have a method such as `ParseObject.create(JSON)` in Android.

The scenario is that I push changes in server data out to relevant clients. The push is send directly from Cloud Code in `afterSave`.

Currently I just notify that a change has been made in a specific class, then the client reacts by fetching all the objects in that class and update the Local Datastore accordingly.

This is not very efficient so it would be nice to be able to simply send the updated object directly using the push and then pin it on the client. Completely avoiding the extra work from fetching and updating all the objects.

Comment: you can convert json to string and then send to server and then when you need it get the string  and convert to json. See if this help

Comment: @Nitin the problem is not on the server. The problem is that if I send a JSON formatted ParseObject from the server to an Android client, then (as far as I know) I have to implement my own way of interpreting the JSON string as a ParseObject.

Comment: I think you have answer :). Just check for some default method. If there is no Method in the api just create it yourself.

Comment: @Nitin The reason I made this question was to hopefully avoid having to write my own logic for each class, handling convertion from JSON to ParseObject. With a little luck, someone else have had the same problem and come up with a solution. Unless I missed something in the docs and it is already possible.

Comment: @WilliamGrand not really. At the moment, I simply pass the updated object in a push msg, locate the object with same id in local datastore and manually update the fields using the received json object. I am using subclassing, so I have added a `updateFromJson()` method to those subclasses I wish to update this way.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is quite old but I think there is a beginning of solution in this [github thread](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/84): since the SDK is open source, we can see that they've a not-open method for that.

I had the same issue and I forked the SDK (and did a bit of git and Gradle! :) ) and it is working pretty well yet! (I wanted to send encrypted ParseObject from CloudCode).

And I had chance because someone did the job I wanted to do on this [commit](https://github.com/evocodes/Parse-SDK-Android/commit/b257a77a3a649dbe3eb2b723bc68585203dc6456) (ok that was not so much!) so it means that you can (kind of) trust the hack!

Hope it helps

Comment: Great find! :) Strange they do not have it public as I can imagine several scenarios where it would be a nice option. I would though be a bit uncomfortable with using a fork as that makes updating the library a bit of a hazel. But in the end this is the only genuine response I have had, so I'll mark it as accepted.